# Plotting a streamplot changing coordinates

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to plot a field given in polar coordinates. This can be done with quiver. However I want to get a streamplot

```
# Field domain in polar coordinates:
R2, THETA2 = np.mgrid[1:3:10j, 0:2*np.pi:10j]

# Field components:
E_y = np.cos(THETA2)*np.sin(THETA2)*(2+3/R2**3)
E_z = (1+2/R2**3)*np.cos(THETA2)**2 + (1+1/R2**3)*np.sin(THETA2)**2

# Get domain in cartesian coordinates:
Z2 = R2*np.cos(THETA2)
Y2 = R2*np.sin(THETA2)

# Plot:
fig2 = plt.figure()
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111)
ax2.quiver(Z2, Y2, E_y, E_z)
ax2.streamplot(Z2, Y2, E_y, E_z)
```

I get the error: `ValueError: The rows of 'x' must be equal`. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`streamplot` expects the input to be a regular grid *in cartesian coordinates*. You have created a grid in *polar coordinates*. To fix this, you can initialize your grid in cartesian coordinates, then convert to polar, compute `E_y` and `E_z` using these polar coordinates and then plot it.

```
# Grid in cartesian coordinates
xrange = np.linspace(-10, 10);
yrange = np.linspace(-10, 10);

xx,yy = np.meshgrid(xrange, yrange)

# Convert each point in grid to polar coordinates
R2 = np.sqrt(xx**2 + yy **2)
THETA2 = np.arctan2(xx, yy)

# Compute direction vectors
E_y = np.cos(THETA2)*np.sin(THETA2)*(2+3/R2**3)
E_z = (1+2/R2**3)*np.cos(THETA2)**2 + (1+1/R2**3)*np.sin(THETA2)**2

# Plot:
fig2 = plt.figure()
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111)
ax2.quiver(xx, yy, E_y, E_z)
ax2.streamplot(xx, yy, E_y, E_z)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know how could I pass the argument of start_points to streamplot?

Comment: @VladimirVargas You would just need to specify the `startpoints` kwarg as specified [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.streamplot) (i.e. `streamplot(x,y,u,v,startpoints=points)`)

Comment: If I pick a couple of points: `points = np.array([[-5, -5], [5, -5]])` I get an error, do you know how to solve that issue?