# Create streamplot in python, ValueError: The rows of 'x' must be equal

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a vector field:

[image]

...but when I want to plot the associated streamplot, I get an error:

> ValueError: The rows of 'x' must be equal

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


NY = 20; ymin = -2.; ymax = 2.
dy = (ymax -ymin )/(NY-1.)
NX = NY
xmin = -2.; xmax = 2.
dx = (xmax -xmin)/(NX-1.)


y = np.array([ ymin + float(i)*dy for i in range(NY)])
x = np.array([ xmin + float(i)*dx for i in range(NX)])

x, y = np.meshgrid( x, y, indexing = 'ij', sparse = False)

Fx  = np.cos(x + 2*y)
Fy  = np.sin(x - 2*y)

F = np.array([Fx, Fy])

# plotting the vectors
plt.quiver(x,y,Fx,Fy)
# Plotting stream plot 
plt.streamplot(x, y, Fx, Fy)

plt.show()
```

Anyone knows why? I have checked the sizes, but they seem equal to me...

Edit:

From the comment section by Trenton McKinney:

"
Note xx and yy in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35990558/plotting-a-streamplot-changing-coordinates/35990851#35990851). Each row is the same, but the values in each row are increasing. The values in each of your rows are the same, but each row is increasing.
"

[image]

... I tried:

```
plt.streamplot(np.transpose(x), np.transpose(y), Fx, Fy)
```

but as you can see the streamplot is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from TrentonMcKinney I realized what the issue was:

In my case:

> The values in each of my rows are the same, but each row is
> increasing.

But what I need for `streamplot` to work is:

> Each row is the same, but the values in each row are increasing.

So I changed `indexing = 'ij'` to `= 'xy'`:

```
x, y = np.meshgrid( x, y, indexing = 'xy', sparse = False)
```

Complete code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


NY = 20; ymin = -2.; ymax = 2.
dy = (ymax -ymin )/(NY-1.)
NX = NY
xmin = -2.; xmax = 2.
dx = (xmax -xmin)/(NX-1.)


y = np.array([ ymin + float(i)*dy for i in range(NY)])
x = np.array([ xmin + float(i)*dx for i in range(NX)])

x, y = np.meshgrid( x, y, indexing = 'xy', sparse = False)

Fx  = np.cos(x + 2*y)
Fy  = np.sin(x - 2*y)

F = np.array([Fx, Fy])

# plotting the vectors
plt.quiver(x,y,Fx,Fy)
# Plotting stream plot 
plt.streamplot(x, y, Fx, Fy)

plt.show()
```

[image]